# Right to Left Shell in SWT

Tags: java, swt, right-to-left

I want to mirror (Right to Left mode) the title bar control buttons (close, minimize and maximize buttons) using SWT in Java. I searched everywhere and came across [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbidi.html) but it does not work for me.

Please help me.

Comment: Which version of SWT are you using?

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to explicitly change the orientation of an SWT control, use

```java
setOrientation( SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT );
```

It is also possible to pass the `RIGHT_TO_LEFT` style flag to the constructor, for example

```
new Shell( parent, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT );
```

Comment: Since v3.7, SWT has a `setOrientation` method on `Control` (which `Shell` inherits from)

Comment: You are right. I used an old version of SWT. It works great now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann can you have a look [here]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816938/combobox-jface-showing-end-of-string-by-default-how-to-show-start-of-long-strin)

Answer (score 0):

A JFace `Window` will contain a SWT `Shell` when opened.

There is the `Shell#setOrientation` API (which is inherited from `Control`, btw). Use that to mirror you controls (check the javadoc).

```
/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class Tester
{

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        shell.setOrientation(SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: But _shell_ does not have a _setOrientation_  method.

Comment: @user3604786 You're most likely using the wrong `Shell` import. :-)