# combobox jface showing end of string by default. How to show start of long string

Tags: combobox, jface

It's an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561924/how-to-stop-jface-combo-box-from-re-sizing-on-a-window-re-size) question. The combobox is resized but it is showing the last characters of the long string. How would I always force the combobox to show the string from the start? 
I checked all the provided methods by ComboBox in jface, but none could qualify to do the task. So I am assuming I would have to write a function for it. But how to go about writing it and attaching that value to combobox. 
Problem : How it is now
How I would like it to be. Just upon selection
[image][image]

Comment: setOrientation(SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT) doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried `viewer.getComo().setSelection( new Point( 0, 0 ) )` after setting the input?

Comment: yes I did. It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you shoud be able to change the selected text of an editable `Combo`/`CCombo` with `setSelection()`.

For example

```java
combo.setSelection( new Point( 0, 0 ) )
```

would position the caret at the beginning of the text field of a combo box.

But apparently this doesn't work (any more?) on SWT on Windows (haven't tried other platforms).

After executing this snippet, the text `begin end` remains entirely selected.
Also, this is seemingly unrelated to the length of the text. Here the entire text fits the width of the Combo. You can also replace `Combo` with `CCombo`, they both behave the same.

```java
shell.setLayout( new FillLayout( SWT.HORIZONTAL ) );
Combo combo = new Combo( shell, SWT.NONE );
combo.add( "begin end" );
combo.select( 0 );
combo.setSelection( new Point( 0, 0 ) );
```

I'd suggest to [file a bug against SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/bugs.php) and see what the SWT maintainers say.

Comment: Filed a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480123) as per your suggestion. What is generally the response time on that?

Comment: I don't know. From my experience, there is no predictable 'response time'. If you need a solution in predictable time you should probably consult professional services.